# Make checkbox checked in WordPress dashboard

Tags: wordpress

I have created some checkbox options for Products in woocommerce WordPress, and I have over 200 products that have the same checkbox clicked. I want to make default checked all checkbox, but also I need that If I want to uncheck any one, they need to save as unchecked.

code:

```
function woocom_general_product_data_custom_field() {

global $post;
$roomforone = get_post_meta($post->ID,"roomforone",true);
$roomforfour = get_post_meta($post->ID,"roomforfour",true);

?>
<div class="all-fields">
 <div class="inner">
    <label for="roomforone" class="room1">Suitable for shipping in Vienna: 
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="roomforone" id="roomforone" value="yes" 
    echo <?php if($roomforone=='yes'){echo "checked='checked'";} else { echo 
    "";} ?>/><br />
 </div>

 <div class="inner">
    <label for="roomforfour" class="room4">Suitable for shipping in Austria: 
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="roomforfour" id="roomforfour" value="yes" 
    echo <?php if($roomforfour=='yes'){echo "checked='checked'";} else { echo "";} ?>/><br />
 </div>

 </div>


function woocom_save_general_proddata_custom_field( $post_id ) {

$roomforone = "no";
if(isset($_POST["roomforone"]))
{
    $roomforone = $_POST["roomforone"];
}
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'roomforone', $roomforone );

$roomforfour = "no";
if(isset($_POST["roomforfour"]))
{
    $roomforfour = $_POST["roomforfour"];
}
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'roomforfour', $roomforfour );


}
```

Comment: `($roomforfour=='yes' || !$roomforfour){echo //whatever}` might work? since it is not set yet, it will be checked - if it is not set, you save it as No

Comment: no, doesn't work this way